How can I see my version of TMS WEB Core during run-time?
This is a strange question and I don't know if it's possible or not, but I want to list on my website's About page that it's built using TMS WEB Core and then I want the version of TMS WEB Core to be listed as well, but I don't want that version to be static. I'd like to somehow dynamically get the version that was used to build it with.
Is there a way to get the TMS WEB Core version dynamically during run-time?

I can see the version listed in two places in my IDE.

When the IDE starts up



In the Tools > Options section



So hopefully I'm able to somehow get the version during run-time also 

Okay.
So I just found that somewhere, there's a WEBCOREVERSION constant variable defined that gives you the version of TMS WEB Core.
My IDE thinks it's an error and says:

E2003 "Undeclared identifier: 'WEBCOREVERSION'


But it compiles and works without any issues. It returns the TMS WEB Core version in run-time. Exactly what I wanted and needed.

What's a "constant variable"?

@AndreasRejbrand It's like a normal variable, but you can't alter their values. Hence, "constant". They're declared with the const keyword instead of the var keyword also: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/Declared_Constants

Where in the documentation does Embarcadero call these things "constant variables"? Normally, they are called "constants". There are variables and there are constants. A constant is, by definition, something that is constant, that never changes. A variable is, by definition, something that varies, that may change over time. So a "constant variable" is a logical contradiction, like a "square circle".

@AndreasRejbrand Many people call it "constant variables", because they are like variables. https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#:~:text=A%20constant%20(const)%20parameter%20is,var%20parameter%20to%20another%20routine. and https://www.google.com/search?q=%2B%22constant+variable%22+Delphi&sca_esv=ab8b5e668a08de67&sxsrf=ACQVn0-AYmgL8lR93K9xj8WDRi6jjrb4ug%3A1713950545835&ei=Uc8oZsLCMsifkdUPqLGfqAE&ved=0ahUKEwiCr8mrw9qFAxXIT6QEHajYBxUQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=%2B%22constant+variable%22+Delphi

I cannot find any occurrence of "constant variable" in the docwiki link you provided. And I have never seen a senior developer use that term. I'm 99% sure that David, Remy, Stefan etc. would never use that term. Of course I'm nitpicking and being really obnoxious know, but I do believe that the phrase is inherently wrong and that most senior devs would react like I did!

constant means "never changes", and variable means "does change", so this term constant variable is an oxymoron

To dynamically retrieve the version of TMS WEB Core used to build your website during runtime, use JavaScript. TMS WEB Core may expose version information through JavaScript variables or functions. Check the documentation or contact the support team to see if they provide a JavaScript API or expose version information. Write JavaScript code to access this information, integrate it into your website's About page, and display it when loaded in the user's browser.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
